# SharePoint Online, get 'clean user-email' in SharePOint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, user-accounts

Trying to get user's e-mail in SPD, but 'E-mail Address' returns string with 'garbage':

> i:0#.f|membership|sharepointpadmin@portal.com

but I need only

> sharepointpadmin@portal.com

[image]

As I've undersood - calculated columns cannot get this e-mail too.
"User Profiles" - "Work E-mail" stores nothing:

[image]

The only approach I see now - is to create hidden field and fill it with javascript. But this is so ugly..

Any ideas?..

Comment: The "garbage" is the authentication method. Are you using "2010" or "2013" style workflows? If 2013, you can use the string Utility Actions to extract the text past the second "|".

Comment: "Email address" returns a proper email address in my SharePoint Online tenant. Maybe your problem has to do with the use of the admin account. What do you get with a normal user account?

Comment: >>"Email address" returns a proper email address in my SharePoint Online  - veery strange.. Workflows version is 2010, and I would prefer to continue to use them.. >>Maybe your problem has to do with the use of the admin account. - Nice idea. I'll try

Comment: Ok, this is a bug!  CreatedBy and People and Group columns return the correct email address. ModifiedBy by does not. Do some tests with various users and see if the prefix data is the same for all. If so, I have a workaround for SP2010 workflows.

Comment: Interesting, seems that 'Created By' for admin account returns garbage too.. @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP, by workaround You mean additional hidden 'People & Group' field, and store value there?

Comment: Tried to use temp field to store e-mail but no luck. I can't use non-admin user. Please provide Your solution if You have one)